# Raspberry pi 3 model B does not boot from USB

Tags: usb, boot, sd-card, pi-3b+, boot-issues

I've got a Raspberry pi 3 model B+, but unfortunately the SD card slot has broken, so I googled about booting RPI3 from USB and I realized it's possible but all tutorial that I've read mentioned that this option need to change the programmable chip in RPI for just one time and this process need SD card for one time, but I can not use my RPI whith the SD card anymore!

Is there any other way to boot RPI 3 from USB without change the programmable chip by booting from SD card?

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ this [procedure](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md) is not necessary.

Simply plug in the USB stick that has been prepared with the image of your choice. The Raspberry Pi will automatically boot from USB when it does not find a bootable microSD card.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Pi3B+ USB boot is pre-programmed  - there is nothing to do.